# JSOUP - troubles with extracting values from two divs

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup, fetch

Hi I trying to get values from two  hidden inputs. (__VIEWSTATE and  __EVENTVALIDATION)

```
<form name="FormLogin" method="post" action="Same.aspx" id="FormLogin">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__OTHER" id="__OTHER" value="SOME not importent value" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/someLongValuewhatIwant=" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/someOtherValueWhatIwant" />
</div>
</form>
```

My code

```
  doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/index.aspx").get();
            Elements input = doc.select("input[type=hidden]");
            Element viewst = input.select("#__VIEWSTATE").get(0);
            Element eventvd = input.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION]").get(0);
            viewstate = viewst.val();
            eventvalidation = eventvd.val();
```

But I always got only __VIEWSTATE value and my app crashed when i try to get __EVENTVALIDATION value. Can someone please explain me why ? and How to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup always crashes android when the select matching expression cannot match any element in the given doc which in  your case`#__EVENTVALIDATION` in not on your input element.
Check in your Elements input if `#__EVENTVALIDATION` exists.

Btw:In your code you can directly access any element by selecting `#id` tag. for example

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://instantgram.ic.cz/index.html").get();


Elements eventvd = doc.select("input[id =__EVENTVALIDATION");
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Everything working well.